# Java calculate the transition between two points over a period of time

Tags: java, swing

I have point A(0,0) and point b(0, 100) and i have a transition time of X ms. I need to move my object form point A to B in the given X ms time. Please help. Some pseudo code would be helpful.

My code for reference :

```
   float time= (float)totalTime / halfTransitionTime;
   new.x = start.x + (end.x - start.x) * time;
   new.y = start.y + (end.y - start.y) * time;
```

But i am not if my time calculation is correct as i do not get the desired output. Please help.

In the above class translateCalc() is the meothod where I do the linear interpolation calculation. I do not seem to get the calculation correct. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Your linear interpolation calculation is correct, but change the time calculation to:

```
float time= ((float)currentTime) / totalTime;
```

This will give you a value between 0 and 1 (assuming `currentTime` is between 0 and `totalTime`), which should result in a smooth transition between `start` and `end`

Comment: in the above code, is currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() and total time =  time to move from point A to point B? When i calculate according to this, it does not seem to work. Please help.

Comment: It depends on how you measure time.  Let's say you start at `startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()`.  Then `currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime`, `totalTime = X` (where X is the desired time length in milliseconds)  This means that as long as `= System.currentTimeMillis()` is between `startTime` and `startTime + X`, `currentTime` is between 0 and X (==totalTime), satisfying the condition in my answer

Comment: I do not still seem to get the time calculation correct. I have posted my original code above by editing my question. Please have a look at the original code and point out where I am going wrong.